# Add shortcode to Navigation block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-block-theme

I am using a FSE theme and I need to add a short code in the navigation block.
I Know there is no direct way to do that but i also have found this hook **block_core_navigation_render_inner_blocks**.
Using that hook works if i try to add the mini-cart (WooCommerce) block but now i need to add a shortcode. The code is:

```
add_filter(
    'block_core_navigation_render_inner_blocks',
    function( $inner_blocks ) { 

        $menu_item = [
            'blockName'    => 'core/shortcode',         
            'attrs'        => [
                "text" => 'fk_cart_menu',               
            ],
            'innerBlocks'  => [],
            'innerHTML'    => '',
            'innerContent' => [],
        ];
        $inner_blocks->offsetSet( null, $menu_item );
        return $inner_blocks;
    }
);
```

I do not see the shortcode in the navigation block. Why?
The shortcode exists, i also checked it with `shortcode_exists()` that returns **true**
I also tried using **[fk_car_menu]** with parentesis, without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the name, the [shortcode block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-shortcode/) doesn't actually return a block; so the *shortcode block* cannot be rendered by `block_core_navigation_render_inner_blocks` as it only renders blocks. This is why in your test, the WooCommerce block worked but the shortcode block did not.

A possible way around this limitation is to [register your own dynamic block](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/) that calls `do_shortcode(...)` in the render callback then use it in your `add_filter(...)` code, eg:

```js
function so78080575_render_callback() {
  // return your shortcode, not echo..
  return do_shortcode( '[fk_cart_menu]' );
}

/* Register a simple, dynamic block */
function so78080575_register_block() {
  if ( !function_exists( 'register_block_type' ) ) {
    // return if block editor unavailable
    return;
  }
  register_block_type( 'so/78080575',
    $args = array(
      'title' => 'FK Cart Menu',
      'icon' => 'smiley',
      'render_callback' => 'so78080575_render_callback' // to render shortcode
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'so78080575_register_block' );


add_filter(
    'block_core_navigation_render_inner_blocks', // accepts only valid blocks
    function( $inner_blocks ) { 

        $menu_item = new WP_Block(['blockName' => 'so/78080575']);
        $inner_blocks->offsetSet( null, $menu_item );

        return $inner_blocks;
    }
);
```

Hopefully this gets you closer to what you are looking to achieve...

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to try your code, just one quick question. Running that code will only show the shortcode on the website right? Or does it render the shortcode inside Site Editor too ?

Comment: You're welcome! In this method, the shortcode will only display on the frontend, it won't appear in the Site Editor. However, if you want to take it further into FSE, you would need alter the `allowedBlocks` of [core/navigation-link](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/navigation-link/block.json) to accept your custom block.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean? WHy do i need to alter? (To directy show my shortcode inside the Site Editor too ?) Thank you!!

Comment: As the core/navigation block heavily restricts what can be added via the inserter in the Site Editor, the [APIs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/) you would need to alter the `allowedBlocks` property are done with React/JavaScript, I haven't got a working example of this yet, but based on other development I've done with blocks, that is the direction I would try..

Comment: Ah ok, to show the block in the side editor too. Ok, got it! Thank you very much